# solve for y: $x = 1 - (1-y)^t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I have the following equation:

$$x = 1 - (1-y)^t$$

I would like to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $t$. I tried *WolframAlpha*, but it did not generate a solution.  Before you ask, yes this is a real problem, no this is not homework.

Comment: $(1-y)^t=(1-x)$. So $1-y=(1-x)^{1/t}$.

Comment: Subtract both sides from $1$, then take logarithms of both sides. Whoops, that solves for $t$, never mind.

Comment: Logarithms are overkill, @MPW, though it works.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : Yes, I thought he was after the exponent. My bad.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews this is the answer, thanks. My mind has forgotten how to get rid of the superscript and account for it on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x = 1 - (1-y)^t$$
$$(1-y)^t=1-x$$
Notice that the following step does not always hold, for example if $t=2$, and $x>1$, we end up with no solution for $y$. But suppose every value is proper, we then have:
$$\bigg( (1-y)^t \bigg)^{1/t}=(1-x)^{1/t}$$
$$1-y=(1-x)^{1/t}$$
$$-y=(1-x)^{1/t} -1$$
$$y=1-(1-x)^{1/t}$$

Comment: No problem! My pleasure.

Comment: The OP states that *Wolfram Alpha* didn't produce the solution, but I found that *Mathematica* gave the correct solution instantly.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sounds like Mathematica is better than wolfram alpha - but could also be the case that OP did not enter the query the way worlfram alpha understands it.

Comment: @YujieZha:  Yep.  When I entered the query properly in *WolframAlpha*, the solution arose immediately.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That's nice, thanks for trying!